The equivalence of Dedekind-infinite and dually Dedekind-infinite as a weak form of (AC)
A set $X$ is Dedekind-infinite if there is an injective map $f: X\to X$ that is not surjective.
A set $X$ is dually Dedekind-infinite if there is a surjective map $f: X\to X$ that is not injective.
In ${\sf (ZF)}$, it is easy to see that any Dedekind-infinite set is dually Dedekind-infinite: Let $f:X\to X$ be a non-surjective injection. Pick $x_0\in X$ and let $g: X\to X$ be defined by $$\big\{\big(f(y), y\big): y\in f(X)\big\}\,\cup\,\big\{(z, x_0):z\in X\setminus f(X)\big\}.$$ Then $g$ is a non-injective surjection.
Consider the statement

(DD) Every dually Dedekind-infinite set is Dedekind-infinite.

It is not hard to see that (AC) implies (DD). Consider the partition principle:

(PP) If $X,Y$ are sets and there is a surjection $f:X\to Y$, then there is an injection $g:Y\to X$.

Question. In ${\sf (ZF)}$, are there any implications between (DD) and (PP)?
Note. It would also be interesting to see whether there is any implication between (DD) and the Dual Cantor Bernstein statement (CB)*, which is implied by (PP) in ${\sf (ZF)}$:

(CB)* If $X,Y$ are sets and $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are surjections, then there is a bijection $\varphi:X\to Y$.


Tarski proved that if there is an infinite Dedekind-finite set, then there is one which is dually Dedekind-infinite as well.
Therefore, postulating that all dually Dedekind-infinite sets are Dedekind-infinite implies that that every Dedekind-finite set is finite.
This is a consequence of $\sf DC$, of course, which is a consequence of $\sf PP$.

Oh, that's a nice theorem. Do you have a reference? (Or a proof sketch?)

Sure. Look at the set of injective finite sequences, then look at the map which trims the last element from the sequence. It's in a few answers around the site, I'm certain, and you can play with the proof even more to get other crazy ideas.

Oh, that's right, I have seen that before. Thanks for the reminder!
